# Get current input language on android (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there any way to get current input language?
I've tried this:

```
editText_input.TextLocale
```

but it returns default system language. Also I tried to look into

```
Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager
```

but no luck as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could only get the keyboard language by using:

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
    InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.CurrentInputMethodSubtype;
    string localeString = ims.Locale;
```

For example:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, it is strange, but it still shows me default system language.

Comment: @obywan What's android version you are using? You could check the keyboard in system setting.

Comment: I'm currently performing tests on 4.4